# Where to place commas

Tags: javascript

I've seen two ways of placing commas when creating multiple variables in JavaScript:

**First method**

```
var a = 0,
    b = '';
```

**Second method**

```
var a = 0
  , b = '';
```

(this difference can also be found on array and object declarations)

Which method is the best and why is it important?

Comment: It doesn' t matter, just be consistent if you can.

Comment: There is no difference,

Comment: Which way do you find more readable? Which one is less likely to be damaged by folk maintaining your code?

Comment: putting comma at both places are same, as you didn't changed the syntax of javascript

Comment: Although this is generally opinion based, comma first is said to help you in not missing it out. Missing it out in javascript can create globals so it's a safety check (i.e. it's clear if you've missed one)

Comment: There is no diff b/w these two it just depends upon you which is suitable for you

Comment: Advantages of 'comma first style' for me are: errors pop out in the comma-first style, when you add a value you only need to add one line (and not an extra comma on the previous line)

Answer (score 6):

Lots of Nodesters are doing 'comma first', but it's mostly just a matter of taste and opinion. There was a long, dragged out discussion about it here:

https://gist.github.com/isaacs/357981

...and then there's this:

https://twitter.com/tjholowaychuk/status/28055285441

Comment: Perhaps due to just posting links... I do not know why

Answer (score 3):

It's totally up to you. There is no difference, except for personal choice of coding-style.

Comment: You toally up to him? That sounds a bit personal :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Which method is the best

Neither.

> why is it important?

It isn't important. It's a style preference.

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of the second method (comma before) is that it makes it easier to comment out a single declaration using the single line comment operator (//)

I've seen a similar method used in large SQL queries when dealing with large 'select' or 'order by' clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to your style of coding.But there is no differences in placing commas.
check the link

[https://css-tricks.com/commas-before/](http://here)